# How can I prevent empty files from showing up on the Ibuffer list?

Tags: ibuffer

On my IBuffer I always see a `*.py`  file that is actually empty.

Is it possible to prevent this file to be hidden in the `Ibuffer` or basically remove it.

```
[ Default ]
    *.py                       0 Python           ~/*.py
```

---

On my configuration, I have folliwng line `(find-file "*.py" t)`, which actually help to speed up the opening time of any Python file on my end (honestly not sure why).

I wasn't able to exclude it as well:

```
(setq recentf-exclude '("__init__.py\\"
            "__init__.py"
            "\\*.py\\'"
            ))
```

More general question should be as: how can I prevent empty files show up on the `Ibuffer list` that will cover `*.py` as well since its empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for ibuffer's filters. Probably this one `/ > 0` which filters for buffers bigger than 0.

If you want to make it "default" from the init file, something like this will do it.

```lisp
(add-hook 'ibuffer-hook (lambda ()(ibuffer-filter-by-size-gt 0)))
```

Although, note two things:

- there are a bunch of `ibuffer-filter` functions, and also a ton of customizable options, in some cases custom defaults may clash with your init file content.
- There are plenty of options and customizations to filter, also for saving, stacking, grouping filters, etc. Probably it'll be a good idea to dig into them.

Type `C-h m` while in `ibuffer` for more info about usage.

Comment: how can I apply `/ > 0` ?

Comment: just type `/ >` in your ibuffer buffer, you'll be asked for the size in the minibuffer, type 0 then `enter`

Comment: Can I set this by default in the `emacs` init file; or like when I call `ibuffer` it will set `files size greater than: 0`

Comment: article updated

Comment: I am not sure is it related to your answer but when I run `ibuffer`, each time `files size greater than: 0` shows up at the top of the file and appends to the buffer and increases file size. Would it be possible to prevent that to huse `[size greater than: 0]` message