# How to prevent `[size greater than: 0]` shown in the iBuffer buffer

Tags: ibuffer

When I run `M-x ibuffer`, it keeps adding `[size greater than: 0]` into top `iBuffer` file, which increases its file size. Would it be possible to prevent it?

`minimal.el`:

```
(add-hook 'ibuffer-hook (lambda ()(ibuffer-filter-by-size-gt 0)))

(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (ibuffer-auto-mode 1)
            (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")))
```

---

// Here first line in the `ibuffer` keeps appending

```
IBuffer by recency (Auto) [size greater than: 0] [size greater than: 0] [size greater than: 0] [size greater than: 0] [size greater than: 0] ....
[ project ]

 MRL Name                    Size Mode             Filename/Process
 --- ----                    ---- ----             ----------------
[ Default ]
     *scratch*                145 Lisp Interaction
 *%  *Messages*               [keep increases] Messages
```

Related questions: [How can I prevent empty files from showing up on the Ibuffer list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62031/18414)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: that message gets added to the header line of the buffer, not to the buffer itself.  And it certainly does not grow: it always contains one instance of the `[size greater than: 0]` message. Do `C-h i g (elisp)Header lines` to read about the header line. Also try `emacs -q -l minimal.el` with a `minimal.el` containing only the above customizations: if it behaves as I describe, the fault is with (the rest of) your init file. That's something that you should *always* check: 99.9% of all problems I encounter are of my own making.

Comment: @NickD Thanks it is ways nice to learn from experts. I have updated my question with the `minimal.el` file I was using. The way I run is `emacs -q -nw -l ~/personalize/emacs/minimal.el doo.py`. I kept doing `M-x ibuffer` and do it again inside the ibuffer-buffer. And `*Messages*               780 Messages` should increment and `[size greater than: 0]` added on the top line. Please note that I am using `GNU Emacs 26.3`

Comment: That's exactly what I mean: you are loading all the packages that you've installed as part of your  so-called "minimal" setup: you need to shed all that in order to test what works and what doesn't, then reintroduce them one step at a time to see what breaks it.

Comment: BTW, `*Messages*` is going to increment in size: everytime anybody  uses `message` it will log a message (by default in the echo area *and* in the `*Messages*` buffer). That can be turned off I think, but I would never do that and I recommend that you don't do it either: being able to look at the messages is an indispensable part of figuring out problems. I would suggest you filter the `*Messages*` buffer from the ibuffer list if you don't want to see it. However, the header line *should not* change.

Comment: Got it, I have tried again by removing all the packages and the same issue exist. Can the returned string could be changed from `[size greater than: 0]` to an empty string`""`? Since we cannot change the header line I will keep everything as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is probably a bad answer, but I no longer know what the question is]

- If you are getting the '[size greater than 0:]` message repeatedly in the header-line and you want to investigate and remove the cause of that, then you need to debug your init file. I cannot reproduce that with a minimal init file containing *just* the following and I assume that you will find the same behavior if you use this minimal init file:

```el
(add-hook 'ibuffer-hook (lambda ()
                          (ibuffer-filter-by-size-gt 0)))

(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (ibuffer-auto-mode 1)
        (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")))

(define-key ctl-x-map (kbd "C-b") #'ibuffer)
```

- If you are worried about the fact that the `*Messages*` buffer is increasing, you should filter out that buffer from the ibuffer listing.
  Interactively, `/*/!` will get rid of all starred buffers; `/n \*Messages\* RET /!` will just filter out the `*Messages*` buffer.
- If you don't want to see the header line at all, you should customize the `ibuffer-use-header-line` option.
- If you want to save a set of filters for future use, you can use `/s <name>` and you can restore those filters later with `/r <name>` or add them to whatever filters you have already defined with `/a <name>`.
- Do `C-h m` in an ibuffer-mode buffer to find out more about what you can do.